# Is it possible to use Chrome's workspaces if you don't have access to the dev server?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I couldn't find a similar question posted so I'm asking here.

I'm trying to understand how to use Chrome's workspaces for development.

My situation is the following: I don't have access to the dev server instead I use a CMS where I sideload snippets of code. My code has to be saved and loaded in a separate window before I see any changes.

I wish to use Chrome's workspaces tool to make live changes to a page that can be saved in a local file.

I saw videos of people doing this and guides too and it seems like you need access to the dev environment of the site to make changes.

Where I'm having difficulties is with the ***map to network resource*** part.

After I add my workspace and map to network resource, should that *resource* be a file that is on the server?

My situation is similar to a student doing a css hack of a website, let's say craiglist.com, and they're using Chrome's workspaces to make changes and save those changes as opposed to editing the styles in the inspector.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where I'm having difficulties is with the map to network resource part.

You can't do this with remote sites. It must be local (or you somehow mount the remote filesystem locally for workspaces) so as you save the files they are then instantly loaded on the next request as the actual server resources.

Chrome does not have resource substitution.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification @Garbee!