# How to use map filesystem folder to debug original sources in Chromium Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, microsoft-edge, chromium

I have a website running at `https://somewebsite.com/`.

- It references a compiled javascript file: `/js/site.js`
- mapping file is also available on the server `/js/site.js.map`
- typescript file is not available - **I'm getting 404 for** `/js/site.ts` which is correct!

I have the original typescript file available locally at `C:/projects/myapp/wwwroot/js/site.ts`

**How do I map my source file in Edge's/Chrome developer tools so that I can debug it?**

When I add `C:/projects/myapp/wwwroot/` local folder to workspace, the files are not linked.

However, when the same website is running on localhost, and I add the local folder to workspace, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @YouZhou answered, I cannot map a local folder, but I can use overrides:

1. Right click the typescript file and choose Save for overrides

   [image]
2. Then paste the content of local file to the overriden file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can only use Workspace with localhost sites. For detailed information, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110871/is-it-possible-to-use-chromes-workspaces-if-you-dont-have-access-to-the-dev-se).

So the only way to map filesystem folder to debug the site is hosting the site in localhost first. About detailed steps of working with Workspaces, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/workspaces/).

Comment: Hi @Liero Is there any update about the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.